# How to access inner class in Java (while in assert)

Tags: java, class, testing, assert, nested-class

I have code here that creates a nested class, and then checks to see if a value is there.  Answer goes where [???] is currently, the code given to me can't be changed.

```
   //The answer must have balanced parentesis
class A{
  class C{
    int foo(){return 42;}
  }
}
public class Exercise{

  public static void main(String [] arg){
   assert ([???].foo()==42);
  }
}
```

The question: how do I access the foo() method within C (which is within A)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run a non-static method of class `C`, you need to create an instance of `C`,but `C` is non-static inner class of A and hence you need to create an instance of `A` before you can create `C`. So, to create `A`:

```
A a = new A();
```

To create C:

```
C c = a.new C();
```

To invoke method foo

```
c.foo()
```

All in one line:

```
new A().new C().foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

dimoniy is correct.

you can also do:

```
A.C c = new A().new C();

assert (c.foo() == 42);
```

Comment: Problem is, then I would have to close the first assert statement